# foreach within a foreach in wordpress is getting the values from the first foreach

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach

Sorry for the confusing title. I am displaying a list of posts in wordpress and using a foreach to display an image,title etc from each post. What I then need is for each post to have a navigation which provides links to the other posts within the same page using anchors.

I have created another foreach within the first one which grabs the same posts again and generates a navigation. This all works fine except the value for each of the navigation links are all the same for every link within each post.

eg if the posts are called post1 and post2, the navigation within post1 should have a link to post1 and post2 but instead both links go to post1. likewise within post2 the navigation should have a link to post1 and post2 but instead both links go to post2:

```
 //first foreach gets all the posts

 <?php
 $portfolioItems = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'category' => 4 );
 $postslist = get_posts( $portfolioItems );
 foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 



// navigation which grabs the same posts and creates a list out of them

<ol>
<?php $portfolioNav = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'category' => 4 );
 $postsnav = get_posts( $portfolioNav );
 foreach ($postsnav as $postnav) :  setup_postdata($postnav); ?>
 <li><a href="<?php the_field('portfolio_anchor'); ?>"><?php the_field('portfolio_anchor'); ?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ol>


// The data getting pulled from the first foreach 
 <div id="<?php the_field('portfolio_anchor'); ?>"></div>
 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<img src="<?php the_field('main_image'); ?>" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe I've missed something but there is no reason to have the second loop. So delete the foreach & get_posts. It should work then

Comment: I think i need the second foreach to create the links to the other posts, otherwise each navigation list would only have 1 link - a link to itself.

Comment: Okay, well in that case just reuse $postslist in your second loop. No need to recall get_posts again

Comment: tried that but when i do that the navigation works but the actual posts on the page are all duplicates of the same one

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it using query_posts instead of get_posts:

```
 <?php query_posts('category_name=Portfolio&posts_per_page=10&orderby=title&order=DESC'); ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Then for the nested query I did the same thing but added wp_reset_postdata at the end of it so it was not overwriting the original query:

```
     <!-- navigation nested query -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span12 foliodivider" style="display: block;">   
    <ol>
    <?php $navNumber = 1; ?>
    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=Portfolio&posts_per_page=10&orderby=title&order=DESC'); ?>
     <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="#<?php the_field('portfolio_anchor'); ?>"><?php echo $navNumber; $navNumber++; ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
   </ol>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- navigation nested query end-->
```

Then finaly added the last endwhile at the very end after I was done using the first query:

```
  <div id="<?php the_field('portfolio_anchor'); ?>"></div>
  <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
  <img src="<?php the_field('main_image'); ?>" />
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```